# How to keep tweepy stream running from Django even after apache server restart?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache, tweepy

I'm building a django-based twitter app that uses Tweepy streaming and I'm curious how to keep the stream running even after the server reboot?

The server is Apache.

Thank you.

Comment: Restarting only the apache service or rebooting the whole server? For Apache there is also a difference between reload and restart. If you are rebooting the whole server all connections vanish.

Comment: @zypro it's about rebooting the whole server. There should be a possibility to run tweepy streaming service on server start.

Comment: If you are just using a python script to start your stream then have a look [to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817011/run-python-script-on-os-boot).